# how to optimize my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `country_data, user_data` and `topic_data` with table structures as given.

**country_data:**

```
name           | code
---------------|---------------
India          | IN
United States  | US
Australia      | AU
```

**user_data:**

```
user_ip        | topic_code    | country
---------------|---------------|---------------
192.168.1.1    | topic_code_1  | India
192.168.1.2    | topic_code_2  | United States
192.168.1.3    | topic_code_3  | Australia
```

**topic_data:**

```
name           | code
---------------|---------------
topic_1        | topic_code_1
topic_2        | topic_code_2
topic_3        | topic_code_3
```

I have about one hundred thousand(100,000) rows in `user_data` table.

What I want is, I need to filter the count of users from each country with its corresponding country code for a given topic. For example, I need the count of users who viewed `topic_2` in each country. The requered output format is

```
country_code   | count
---------------|---------------
IN             | 150
US             | 120
AU             | 100
```

Now please check my query:

```
SELECT cd.code, COUNT(ud.country) as count 
FROM topic_data as td, user_data as ud, country_data as cd 
WHERE td.name = 'topic_1' AND td.code = ud.topic_code AND ud.country = cd.name 
GROUP BY ud.country
```

This one takes about 2 seconds to complete the execution in phpmyadmin. In the php webpage, it takes 15 seconds to load the page even in the server. by removing the group by in the query, ie `GROUP BY ud.country`, it takes more than 30 seconds to execute and the output is with the last country code and total of all countries visits. what am I doing wrong? please help.

**----UPDATE----**

Altered the tables using foreign keys and so as my queries too. now it works with lightning speed. thanks for those who helped.

Comment: Primary key optimization?  Why do you store full text for country rather than the unique key that would be available in your country table?

Comment: What indexes do the tables have? Can you provide the `EXPLAIN` plan of the query?

Comment: Please add your database tables' definition queries. We need to see your indexes, primary keys, foreign keys and table engines.

Comment: @Jon user_data table is old one and the country_data table is added by me for this purpose. I can't change the table. by doing so, it will affect so many pages.

Comment: probably should store country code instead of the full country name in your user data table, another way is create a view using your above query. in your php page just do a select * to it, theoretically should be faster.

Comment: @STTLCU the primary key is just an auto increment field in each table. no foreign keys.

Comment: That is your problem than.  You need to set up the tables correctly, and if you feel you can't, you've made your application in a way that can't be upgraded by a script.  To cut down on the query, you really do need foreign keys assigned and available.

Comment: can you please provide me some simple tutorial links for these.

Comment: @Jianhong topic name is a dynamic variable. so how can I create a view for this query?

Comment: you create a generic view, without the condition, then you query the view with the condition = "topic name"

Comment: @Jianhong oopz.. I didn't something illegal. I couldn't create the view. It didn't worked as I expected. I request your help.

Comment: This may not be orthodox
create view whatever_view_name as
SELECT td.name, cd.code, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM topic_data as td, user_data as ud, country_data as cd 
WHERE td.code = ud.topic_code AND ud.country = cd.name 
GROUP BY td.name;

SELECT code, SUM(count)
FROM whatever_view_name
WHERE name = "topic_1"
GROUP BY code

Comment: @Jianhong the count shows is for each td.name right? and the cd.code shows is just the last one only. then how can I filter it for each contry?

Comment: Storing country code (hopefully they're the ISO ones....) will help if you every need to start localizing your data (ie, having names of countries in more than one language).

Comment: if you don't want to store country code then change the query to store country name it is totally up to you. the 2nd query group by already is a filter. i'm just sharing another avenue where you can explore and hopefully you are able to achieve whatever you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query doesn't look too bad IMO. However the normalization of the data looks a bit strange, e.g. why would you have a `country` (name) field on `user_data` table, just to join into `country` on name to look up the code? Instead, the more logical thing to me would be to reference country by country code (or other indexed key constraint). This would also save a join to country, if you just need the code as per your example query. If `user_data` is a high volume table, you will want to keep the data in it to a minimum to reduce IO when reading (density).

Also, as an aside, joining using `JOIN` instead of in the `WHERE` clause will improve the readability of your code, IMO:

```
SELECT cd.code, COUNT(ud.country) as count
FROM topic_data as td
  INNER JOIN user_data as ud
    ON td.code = ud.topic_code
  INNER JOIN country_data as cd
    ON ud.country = cd.name
WHERE td.name = 'topic_1'
GROUP BY ud.country;
```

To address the performance issues, check that the following indexes are in place:

- Index on `topic_data.name`
- Index on the foreign keys `user_data.topic_code` and `user_data.country` (or `user_data.country_code` if you do change the foreign key to `user_data.country_code`)

Comment: I hope you missed a ON after the second INNER JOIN

Comment: I tried this query. It works fine after the first execution in localhost. but still have the problem in server. consequent executions only reduces time. first Query took 0.9851 sec in phpmyadmin. let me try optimizing the values. thanx....

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

use below database structure for using numerical matching in INNER JOIN statement may decrease search time,
so index your id column of tables (e.g. primary key):

```
**country_data**  
id|name           | code
--|---------------|---------------
1 |India          | IN
2 |United States  | US
3 |Australia      | AU

**user_data**
user_ip        | topic_id  | county_id
---------------|-----------|---------------
192.168.1.1    | 1         | 1
192.168.1.2    | 2         | 2
192.168.1.3    | 3         | 3

**topic_data**
id|name           
--|------------
1 |topic_1   
2 |topic_2
3 |topic_3
```

and run multiple INNER JOIN statment like:

```
SELECT cd.code, count(ud.topic_code) as count
FROM ud
INNER JOIN cd ON cd.id = ud.country
INNER JOIN td ON td.id = ud.topic_code
WHERE td.code='topic_1'
GROUP BY ud.country;
```